# Using conda-index with S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, conda

I am hosting my own private conda channel on S3, but I don't understand how to avoid mirroring all the packages on my local hard drive. The source of the problem is the `repodata.json`, `channeldata.json`, etc. files.

If I build a single package and copy just the `.tar.bz2` file to S3, `conda-install` does not see it in the channel. In order for `conda-build` to see the package, I have to copy the package and all of the `repodata.json`, etc. metadata files created by `conda-build` to S3.

My conundrum is: these JSON metadata files do not appear to be updated properly unless all of the packages I've ever built appear in my local package directory. I now have more than 4GB of conda packages on my local hard drive so that I get the correct metadata in these JSON files.

Is there a way to continue building conda packages with my local machine while avoiding mirroring my private S3 conda channel on my local hard drive? For what its worth, I realize that `conda-index` will build the JSON files, but it doesn't seem to work when you attempt to index a location on S3.

Comment: FWIW, I asked a similar question on the `conda-build` issue tracker: https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/3259

Answer (score 0):

One way to host a private conda channel in s3 and build packages there is to mount the s3 bucket as a FUSE filesystem ([goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys) works well for this task) and then run `conda build` and `conda index` locally.